# aggregate function like for characters in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, char, integer, aggregate-functions

In case of integers, there are aggregate functions such *max, min* to find the high and low values in a table.

How to do the same for character type? I mean, If a column as a value repeated more than once, and I want to display that value. How to query that?

for example, I have a table `programmer`
and columns such as `programmer, lang1, lang2`which has many values in those like programmer column has *abu, babu, catherine, david* and lang1 column has *basic, c, basic, sql* and lang2 has *pascal, pascal, c, cobol*.

My objective is to display the maximum repeated value in lang2 column.

Comment: Show sample data and desired output

Comment: Okay. I have a table called program and columns such as programmer, lang1, lang2 and many values entered in those columns. 'lang1' has pascal,pascal,pascal,cobol like values, and I wanna get the result like which language was opted by most of the programmer

Comment: question is not clear, do you want find rows duplicate column values?

Comment: i want to extract the maximum repeated value alone. In the above example, it was pascal.

Comment: `max()` and `min()` will work for character data as well. **Edit** your question and add some sample data (_formatted_ **text** please) and the expected output based on that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT lang, COUNT(lang) 
FROM pgm
GROUP BY lang
ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1
```

---

This select query yields maximum repeated language in column `lang` and its total count

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0bf36/1)